# Rails Devise Flash[:notice] not showing up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

A am new to devise, and just set it up with default functionality.
I cannot get the flash[:notice] messages to show up.

I put this in my application.html.erb file

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %> 
  <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" %> 
<% end %>
```

I can get the error messages like "already logged in" but I cannot get the regular notice messages like "Signed in successfully."

Can anyone point me in the direction of why this is not working.
I just want to use the defaults I dont care about having custom notices.

Answer (score 0):

Try the change below.

`<%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => name %>`

Comment: Does "already logged in" display with the change above? :notice still absent? Just checking, did you run the devise generators, etc.?

Comment: I did run the generators, and notice is still absent.  Already logged in still shows up.  Just not standard log out, log in, and signed up